# Expandable view on checkbox click Android

Tags: android, view

I'm looking for a way to expand a view when someone clicks on a checkbox.
If checkbox = true, the view expands. if false the view folds.
The basic idea is that I have a class newPokerGame and if the game is a tournament (the checkbox) some view will expand and you can select how many players etc.

I only don't know what's the best way to implement this. Any ideas?
Greets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to listen to checkbox toggle, use `onCheckChangedListener`

```
yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked ) {
        // show the view
        } else {
        // hide the view
        }
    }
});
```

to implement "expanding" view, create the layout that you'd want to expand/collapse as you want it to be seen in expanded mode, and just set the visibility of the layout that encloses it inside onCheckChanged. use View's `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` 
or `setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I implement the expandable view?